# Python: how pass string as a function's argument

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with US state abbreviations:

```
state
tx
ca
fl
wa
ny
az
```

I'm trying to get full names with the `us.states` module

```
df['state_ru'] = df.state.apply(lambda x: us.states.x.upper().name)
```

And it returns

```
AttributeError: module 'us.states' has no attribute 'x'
```

I'm unclear how to pass the `x` into the `us.states` module to produce what I'm looking for.

Expected results:

```
state  state_ru
tx     Texas
ca     California
fl     Florida
wa     Washington
ny     New York
az     Arizona
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `us.states` module has a lookup method you can use:

```
import us
df['state_ru'] = df.state.apply(lambda x: us.states.lookup(x).name)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) like this

```
getattr(obj, 'foo')
```

This is equivalent to doing : `obj.foo` and is very useful when the attribute name is variable.